# Ubuntu can not find keyboboard keys

Tags: keyboard-layout, hp, 19.10, kde5, keys

I have HP ProBook 450 G6 with Ubuntu 19.10 and KDE Plasma. F Keybord keys like always controll various system functions, but system 'thinks' that
<kbd>F8</kbd> is also <kbd>F3</kbd>,<kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>F5</kbd>. So when I try to assign function to any of these keys system recognise all of them as <kbd>F8</kbd>, which primary function is to turn microphone on/off. And If I change any of these keys all of them changes. Like all of them has the same ID. How can I change this,is there any 'tell' system that that are different keys. Thank you in advance.
**NOTE:** I am using Croatian keyboard layout(QWERTZ), but if I change layout,everything is the same.